# How to use single quotes within double quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, string, escaping, quotes

Creating a link in PHP:

```
echo "<a href=\"$currentFile?rowID=$row['id']\">click here</a>";
```

This throws an error: `Parse error: parse error, expecting 'T_STRING' or 'T_VARIABLE' or 'T_NUM_STRING'`. How can you do this?

Also, mixing single and double quotes, and escaping double quotes reduces readability and always generates errors. Is there a better way to create quotes with another syntax, like %Q() in Ruby?

Working PHP 5.2.8.

Comment: it's not required, but this is how I prefer to do what you're doing: `echo '<a href="'.$currentFile.'?rowID='.$row['id'].'">click here</a>';`

Comment: Agreed, this way it is clearer by delimiting strings from variables.

Comment: @andrewjackson - I've done it that way too, but I find it difficult to read and error prone.

Comment: @BSeven Jw, but are you using a code editor with syntax highlighting?

Comment: @andrewjackson - Yes, Dreamweaver.

Comment: @BSeven oh, then I guess it's just a matter or personal preference. either way is fine... for you, you could either wrap it in curly brackets `{$row['id']}`, or just get rid of the single quotes. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9628162/779092)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your array variable interpolation. The syntax is either

```
"$row[id]"
```

or

```
"{$row['id']}"
```

So:

```
"<a href=\"$currentFile?rowID=$row[id]\">click here</a>"
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.

Answer (score 3):

If quotes get confusing, which they can, try heredoc syntax:

```
echo <<< END_HTML
    <a href="$currentFile?rowID=$row[id]">click here</a>
END_HTML;
```

...just make sure that the **END_HTML;** is on a line by itself, with no indentation and no trailing whitespace.  Here, heredoc is overkill.  But for larger HTML blocks with lots of variables it can be much easier than escaping quotes everywhere.

[PHP heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the variables in `{}` like this `{$currentFile}` and `{$row['id']}`.

Answer (score 2):

sprintf is your friend for complex strings with variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
echo sprintf('<a href="%s?rowID=%d">click here</a>', $currentFile, $row['id']);
```

Here I assume that $currentFile is a string (you could further manipulate the string, perhaps with `urlencode`) and $row['id'] is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

for named arrays inside of double quotes, you should not use single quotes:

```
echo "<a href=\"$currentFile?rowID=$row[id]\">click here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to echo HTML-Code in single quotes and their tags in double quotes for the reason of clarity. When someone else looks over your code a ton of escaped quotes makes it just look complicated.

e.g

```
echo '<a id="testlink" alt="blabla" href="test.php?somevar='.$xy.'">Test</a>';
```