# Php variable not printing any value

Tags: php

In PHP I am writing:

```
$link = "<a href='/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs='. $cat .'>5.000€</a>";
```

But the value "$cat" is not showing anything.
Any suggestion?

Consider that if I write in HTML:

```html
<a href="<?php echo '/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=<?php echo $cat; ?>">5.000€</a>
```

It works...

Probably it is something I am missing in the sintax.
Thank you!

Comment: You have there bad quotes.

Comment: `<?php 

echo $link = "<a href='/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs='. $cat .'>5.000€</a>";`

Comment: I cannot use " inside the variable

Comment: Might be of help: [using single quotes within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628117/how-to-use-single-quotes-within-double-quotes-in-php).

Comment: actually even "echo" I cannot use. It is inside a PHP file with several variables I call from a PHP page

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this:

```
<?php

$cat = $_GET['categoria_cqs'];//(to get the value from the session)
$link = "<a href='/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=$cat'>5.000€</a>";

?>
```

I still cannot understand why I had to get it again (in HTML it worked without it) but that is fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the quotes, your line should look like this:

```
$link = '<a href="/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs='. $cat .'">5.000€</a>';
```

Remember that the string must be closed with the same quotation mark as it was opened.

Additionally, remember that the character " " and ' ' can "escape" themselves, [as MoarCodePlz said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7999163/14951649).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your real purpose is, if it is to create this directly in PHP or not, but maybe the code below will help you, I created a variable that will store the website URL that will pass the `$cat` variable as a parameter, to see the result I used the `<a>` tag in html

The code would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $cat = 'Pathname';
    $link = "https://yourwebsite.com/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=' . $cat . '";
    ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">5.000€</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to get the result only in PHP, use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $cat = 'Pathname';

    $link = "<a href='/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=" . $cat . "'>5.000€</a>";

    echo $link;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

You say that your code works only using HTML and not in PHP. Well, I've been analyzing it here and I saw that this was happening due to the fact that the file is in a directory, right? PHP was not understanding that the URL was from this directory, at least for me the error was this one in addition to the quotes

Please try the code below, I believe it will work in both PHP and HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $cat = $_GET['categoria_cqs'];

    $link = '<a href="/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=' . $cat . '">5.000€</a>';
    echo $link;
    ?>

    <a href="/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=<?php echo $cat; ?>">5.000€</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, probably the variable is not stored, but if I write directly in HTML like this
<a href="/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=<?php echo $cat; ?>">5.000€</a>
it works... I cannot understand why

Comment: In your PHP file, try to change `' . $cat . '` to `" . $cat . "`

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the variable is empty only if I write the link in PHP
$link = "<a class='box' href='/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=" . $cat . "'>5.000€</a>";

but if I write directly in HTML like this 
<a href="/?s=cqs3&importo_desiderato=5000&categoria_cqs=<?php echo $link; ?>">5.000€</a> it works... 
I cannot understand why

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if it's working now

Comment: it worked while I GET back the variable value from the session (I posted my solution). Thank you